# c database program using structs

Tags: c, database, struct

I'm make a program in c that display a database using structures, I'm kinda new to programming also I know c++ and i make the program also for c++ but I have a problem in both programs. I will post only the c code. So the program works fine until I saw that is not printed the values I entered, it prints random values(it's garbage memory I guess). I don't know why this is working have a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
typedef struct database{
char dataname[32],date[32];
int  number_employers;
float  profit;
double salary;
}database;
void new_company(database x);
void show_company(database x);

int main()
{
database Tarom,Wizzair;
new_company(Tarom);
system("cls");
new_company(Wizzair);
system("cls");
show_company(Tarom);
show_company(Wizzair);
return 0;
}

void new_company(database x){
printf("Enter company name: ");
scanf("%s",&x.dataname);
printf("\nEnter company date: ");
scanf("%s",&x.date);
printf("\nEnter number of employers:");
scanf("%d",&x.number_employers);
printf("\nEnter the average salary of employers:");
scanf("%f",&x.salary);
printf("\nEnter the company profit(in proccent):");
scanf("%f",&x.profit);
}

void show_company(database y){
printf("Company name:%s\n",y.dataname);
printf("Company date:%s\n",y.date);
printf("Number of employers:%d\n",y.number_employers);
printf("Average salary of employers:%f\n",y.salary);
printf("Company profit:%f\n***************************\n",y.profit);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just asking "please debug my code" is not the way this side works (please take a look at "how to ask"). What did you try and what did you get ?

Comment: @FUZxxl, The original question looked to me like a perfectly fair request for information about the same issue in both C and C++.  The significant part of question was the same in C and C++;  But the best answer was different between C and C++.  So it turned out to be a good idea to ask for both.  It is very often correct to push back against beginners who use both C and C++ tags when they only are interested in one.  But this post did not deserve that expert hijack.

Comment: @JSF There are subtle differences between C and C++, even in the overlapping part. Under no circumstances should beginners think that they can compile C code as C++ just fine. Thus the strict policy that a question must specify at most one programming language in which the problem is to be solved, except if the question is about the interaction of multiple programming languages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`void new_company(database x){`

You passed the object by value, so the function gets a local copy.  Any changes to the object made inside the function affect only the local copy, not the original.  That is your problem.

In C++, the correction to that problem is simpler.  You just change the signature of the function to

```
void new_company(database& x){
```

In C, the change is more difficult.  You need `&` in front of the object name where the caller passes it to the function, and you need `*` in front of the name in the function signature, and you need to change all the `.` used to access members of the object inside the function to `->`

Comment: Thanks mate it works, i changed all function as you said but  it gives me a program crash after i type in the console this line: scanf("%d",x->number_employers); I managed to fix it introducing an & in front of x, however this lines works without & in front: scanf("%s",x->dataname); and scanf("%s",x->date); So why there is no crash and it is better to use & or leave as they are?

Comment: In most contexts the name of an array, such as `x->dataname` represents the address of the first element of the array.  The name of a scalar, such as `x->number_employers` refers to the value.  `scanf` needs an address of where to store the result, regardless of whether it is reading a number or a char array.  So it needs the `&` to make `x->number_employers` an address while `x->dataname` is already an address.

Answer (score -1):

Because you're passing the database object by value, so a copy of the (uninitialized) dictionary objects is being passed in, and it's this copy that's being updated by new company.  Pass in the address of the dictionaries, e.g.

```
new_company(&Tarom);
```

and change new_company definition to take a pointer to a database, like:

```
void new_company(database* x){
```

Comment: would whoever down-voted these answers care to share a reason?